# Determining A Formula Based On Known Variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a list of numbers that will result in a number, however I don't know the formula in which the number is created.

In what ways could I go about solving this. For example

- 214, 49, 244 = 13
- 215, 49, 214 = 13
- 216, 49, 55 = 13
- 217, 49, 16 = 13
- 425, 48, 38 = 13

Comment: $f(a,b,c)=13$ for all $a,b,c$? Unfortunately, specifying the values of a function $f$ at a finite number of points cannot, in principle, tell us a general formula for $f$.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is correct. All I have are the input values. Reading further, I realise there is no scientific way to produce a formula, it looks like it is more an art than science.

Comment: There *are* methods for producing formulas that (sometimes) fit data completely, or, if you are a statistician, at least reasonably well.

Comment: Do you have a reference to any of these methods that I could look further into?

Comment: Not offhand. For fitting a polynomial completely, one uses finite differences. For statistical fitting, there is the method of least squares. One makes a guess as to the **type** of formula that might give a good fit. It will have undetermined parameters. One finds "good" values of the parameters by using least squares. However, nothing of this type seems applicable to your problem. The best guess is unfortunately the constant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $f(a,b,c) = A*a + B*b + C*c$   I have found the following values:

```
A = 0.0012461
B = 0.25978929
C = 1.3469E-05
```

The residual sum-of-squares error is 6.27E-07. It might make sense to add a constant term and/or some quadratic terms, but that's try-and-error.

Comment: Thanks Axel, can I ask how you generated those numbers?

Comment: Nothing sophisticated, just the "Solver Add-in" of Excel 2007